# OpenCL Crashes with big input array

Tags: c++, c, opencl

Using this example for mac [Click Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/ExampleHelloWorld/Example_HelloWorld.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008312-CH112-SW2)

I am getting OpenCL to crash for big arrays (Put NUM_VALUE=10000). Any suggestions on why that would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the program in a debugger, like gdb to know for sure. it could be one of these allocations:

```
float* test_in = (float*)malloc(sizeof(cl_float) * NUM_VALUES);

void* mem_in  = gcl_malloc(sizeof(cl_float) * NUM_VALUES, test_in, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR);

void* mem_out = gcl_malloc(sizeof(cl_float) * NUM_VALUES, NULL, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY);
```

returning NULL for the memory request, as this program does not check that, causing the next access on one of these arrays to segfault.

Comment: The program doesn't crash during the execution of the main, but the kernel. I get a weird error that I believe means that the kernel does not respond and I have to terminate debugging through the debug button.